RC series analysis with H parameters model
I'm writing this just to be sure I understood well the process of analysing a circuit with the \$H\$ parameters model. In this case, it is a very simple example of application; the circuit I'm considering is the following:

I will call \$v_1,v_2\$ the voltages and the input and at the output, respectively, of the model, while \$i_1, i_2\$ will be the related currents. Here I'm considering an ideal voltage source, so we will have \$V_S = v_1\$. I will call the parameter of the left-hand side of the model \$h_{11}\$ and \$h_{12}\$, while those of the right-hand side will be called \$h_{21}\$ and \$h_{22}\$.
To give a better image of the model I'm using, I will upload the following image:

For \$h_{11}\$, since this is equal to \$v_1/i_1\$ with \$v_2 = 0\$ and we have \$V_S = v_1\$, then we also have \$i_1 = V_S/R\$ because of the fact that the capacitor \$C\$ is shorted by the fact that \$v_2 = 0\$, so the circuit with \$v_2 = 0\$ is just a voltage source in series with the resistor \$R\$.
For \$h_{12}\$, this is equal to \$v_1/v_2\$ at \$i_1 = 0\$. Since \$i_1=0\$, this means that no current will run through \$R\$, so there will be no voltage drop across \$R\$ and, then, \$v_1\$ will be the voltage across \$C\$, but also \$v_2\$ is the voltage across \$C\$, so \$v_1 = v_2\$ and \$h_{12} = 1\$.
For \$h_{21}\$, this is equal to \$i_2/i_1\$ with \$v_2 = 0\$. Again, the capacitor is shorted, so the current flowing out of every point in the circuit will be \$i_1\$, but the current flowing in will be \$i_2\$, so \$i_1=-i_2\implies h_{21} = -1\$.
For \$h_{22}\$, this is \$i_2/v_2\$ with \$i_1 = 0\$. No current is running through \$R\$, so the remaining circuit is just the right-hand mesh; this implies that \$v_2\$ is the voltage across \$C\$ and \$i_2\$ is the current running through \$C\$, so \$i_2/v_2\$ will be the reverse of the impedance of the capacitor \$C\$, hence \$h_{22} = j\omega C\$.
With this, I can construct the matrix \$H\$ and easily compute the voltage amplification of the circuit.
Are all these explanations right? Thank you in advance for your help!
EDIT: adjusted the notation of the question (formatting it with latex) and I added the scheme for the linearised \$H\$ parameters model.

Given \$\left[\begin{matrix}v_1\\i_2\end{matrix}\vphantom{\begin{matrix}R\\sC\end{matrix}}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}h_{11}&h_{12}\\h_{21}&h_{22}\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}i_1\\v_2\end{matrix}\vphantom{\begin{matrix}R\\sC\end{matrix}}\right]\$: when \$v_2=0\$ you get \$\left[\begin{matrix}v_1\\i_2\end{matrix}\vphantom{\begin{matrix}R\\sC\end{matrix}}\right]=i_1\left[\begin{matrix}h_{11}\\h_{21}\end{matrix}\right]\$ and when \$i_1=0\$ you get \$\left[\begin{matrix}v_1\\i_2\end{matrix}\vphantom{\begin{matrix}R\\sC\end{matrix}}\right]=v_2\left[\begin{matrix}h_{12}\\h_{22}\end{matrix}\right]\$. So it's obvious that \$h_{11}=\frac{v_1}{i_1}\$, \$h_{21}=\frac{i_2}{i_1}\$, \$h_{12}=\frac{v_1}{v_2}\$, and \$h_{22}=\frac{i_2}{v_2}\$ under their stated conditions.
\$h_{11}\$ and \$h_{21}\$ have the output shorted. So \$h_{11}=R\$ and \$h_{21}=-1\$. The only reason for the sign of \$h_{21}\$ has to do with the defined direction of \$i_2\$, which is opposite the direction of \$i_1\$ in this case.
\$h_{12}\$ and \$h_{22}\$ have the input open. So \$h_{12}=1\$, because \$v_1=v_2\$ here, and \$h_{22}=sC\$, the conductance of the capacitor.
Suppose you want to check and see if you can get the transfer function, which is \$G_s=\frac{1}{1+sRC}\$. In this case the output is open, not shorted, so \$i_2=0\$. And \$v_1\$ can be taken as given, for now (we'll divide by it, later.) So we want: \$\left[\begin{matrix}h_{11}&h_{12}\\h_{21}&h_{22}\end{matrix}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{matrix}v_1\\0\end{matrix}\vphantom{\begin{matrix}R\\sC\end{matrix}}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}i_1\\v_2\end{matrix}\vphantom{\begin{matrix}R\\sC\end{matrix}}\right]\$.
This works out to \$G_s=\frac{v_2}{v_1}=\frac{1}{1+sRC}\$, which is exactly as desired.
I'm not entirely following what you expect in an answer. But I didn't find mistakes made in your results and your process seems reasoned well. If there's something else in there you are asking, I haven't worked out what it is, yet.

I just wanted to get confirmed that my reasonings were correct, thank you for doing that!
